# Ubuntu server hosting

Tags: http, dns

I have a webpage for the teachers at the school, and it's found on localhost. (`192.168.1.1`)
I can reach that page out of school also. (`example.com`)
I want to solve the following: If they at the school and want to open `example.com`, don't have to go to the internet and back to the school with the request.
I want to host all `example.com` requests to `192.168.1.1` at the inner server. And if someone  called `example.com` at the school, it would be over LAN and if out of school, it would be over Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose between (I would rather the second one):

1) Modify the "hosts" file in each machine (by hand) to force example.com to 192.168.1.1 (it is hard)

You can find this file:

Windows: %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (by default the system root is c:\windows, so if you are using Windows, your hosts file is most probably c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Linux: /etc/hosts

Mac OS X: /private/etc/hosts

2) Set up a transparent proxy at school, so all requests will go through this proxy, and you will only have to add this rule in your new proxy machine.

Comment: I will solve it with a JS at the begining of the index.html. It's the most easier. Thank you for helping.